# In which cases git merge --no-ff is not keeping the commit history?

Tags: git

I have a development branch called `devel`, a feature branch called `feature_1`, and a testing branch called `testing`. This is what I've done:

- `feature_1` branched from `devel`
- commits were made here, to implement the feature
- `feature_1` was merged to `testing`
- some bugs were discovered on `feature_1` ( with `--no-ff` )
- additional commits have been made to `feature_1`
- in the mean time, a hotfix has been merged to `devel`, and `feature_1` has not been rebased
- `feature_1` has been merged again to `testing`, with `--no-ff` )
- all the tests on branch `testing` were succesful, and the `feature_1` branch can be merged back into `devel`
- I merged `feature_1` into `devel` with `--no-ff`, but instead of the merge copying all the commits that were created on the `feature_1` branch, it only created a merge commit saying that the `feature_1` branch has been merged.

Could anyone explain why the --no-ff did not preserve the commit history? I'm inclined to say that it's because the `feature_1` branch hasn't been rebased against `devel`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But merge --no-ff *always* create *one* commit. The history of commits is referenced in one of the parents of the commit merge. Where is the problem?

Comment: Usually, I think it copied all the commit history as well.

Comment: Can you check that with `git log`?

Comment: Were you using the command line, or a GUI tool that requested --ff? In the latter case it could have seen that --ff was not possible and hence created a merge commit, history and all.

Comment: @PhilipOakley I was using the command line.

Comment: @VonC in this specific case, if I rebase, I get the commit history.

Comment: @Tempus true, that was `rebase` does. A `merge --no-ff` though will always generate *one* commit.

Comment: @VonC, if you want to add an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to [`git rebase`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), which by default will keep the history of commits, a [`git merge --no-ff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) generates by design *one* commit.
So what you see after merging `feature_1` into `devel` with `--no-ff` is normal.

```
--no-ff
```

> Create a merge commit even when the merge resolves as a fast-forward.